# ¿Cómo instalar librería telegram.ext en Google Colab?

Tags: librería, telegram, telegram-bot, google-colab

Tengo el código en python de un bot de Telegram funcional y quiero subirlo a Google Colab, pero al momento de intentarlo me da error en la librería de **telegram.ext**. E intentado instalar las librerías de diversas maneras pero no encuentro la solución, alguien sabe como instalarlas o que hacer para que funcionen?

Adjunto imágenes de las librerías así como del error.

[image: Librerías]

[image: Error]

Answer (score 0):

Puedes instalar la librería [python-telegram-bot](https://github.com/python-telegram-bot/python-telegram-bot):

```
%pip install python-telegram-bot
```